# Regexp result to global map (scala)

Tags: regex, scala, parsing

I've got simple question:

I want to have a map of values that is a result of parsing text:

```
example.txt
Anna
James
Katy
```

So as a result it should be big map - something like this:

```
user_1 : Anna
user_2 : James
user_3 : Katy
```

I want to use case class for holding it separately from parse logic:

```
case class UserMap(userMap: Map[String, String])
```

So, i'm starting to parse it and i need something familiar:

```
(pseudo-scala)
  def parseTxt: Parser[UserMap] = ".*".r ^^ {
    case res => User(("user_1" -> res))
  }
```

What is the best approach here? How to use map in this case? Thank you

Comment: What... Can't you just open the file in scala, read line by line and add each line as a user in a map. Why do you need something like a Parser... ?

Comment: And what is a global map ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh this is just an example: in real case scenario it is a big XML file, global map is just a simple map, so i need use Regexp to use properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If at all price you want to use the Scala parser combinators, then here is a solution:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

object SO29918479 extends App {
  case class UserMap(userMap: Map[String, String])

  object UserParser extends RegexParsers {
    def user: Parser[String] = """[a-zA-Z]+""".r
    def users: Parser[List[String]] = (user ~ "\n".?).* ^^ ( _.map(_._1))
    def userMap: Parser[UserMap] = users ^^ { a =>
      UserMap(a.zipWithIndex.map({case (user, index) => s"user_$index" -> user}).toMap)
    }
  }

  println(UserParser.parse(UserParser.userMap, "Anna\nJames\nKaty"))
}
```